# What is a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, terminology, definition

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes), a smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders. I don't understand what this means if the case was for example the function $$f(x) = 1+2x$$  This can be differentiated only twice until it is zero. Is this considered a smooth function? I am confused about the definition.

Comment: You can differentiate $1+2x$ forever. You get $2,0,0,0,\dots$

Comment: It is considered a smooth function because you *can* differentiate the zero function.. you just get the zero function back.

Comment: For example, $\lvert x\rvert$, the absolute value function, is not smooth, since you can't even differentiate it once. (There is no derivative at $0$.)

Answer (score 2):

The function $h(x)=0$ is differentiable with $h'(x)=0$. So yes your function is smooth.

Note that in some contexts smooth can mean different things, such as 1 or 2 times differentiable. Sometimes we don't need all derivatives, so smooth just means "as many as I need".

Comment: Does a smooth function in most contexts have to be continues? For example would you consider $1/x$ and $\tan(x)$ to be smooth functions?

Comment: @fibonatic First, the word is "continuous", not "continues". Second a function has to be differentiable to be smooth, what is the relationship between continuity and differentiability?